# Criar mapa personalizado utilizando corelocation

Tags: swift, xcode

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de inserir um mapa feito por você e não o google maps.

Estou tentando criar um aplicativo indoor location e tenho que inserir uma planta ao invés do google maps. Alguém ai sabe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `MapKit`, https://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial

Vai usar o mapa nativo da apple, caso você não queira usar esse você pode usar o `MapBox`, https://www.mapbox.com/ que é uma solução de mapas que também é utilizado.

Espero ter te ajudado =D

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.

Comment: Não há necessidade de ficar replicando o código, o Danilo pode entrar no link e ver a sua resposta.